# Visual Studio 2013: cannot open include file.h, despite having set include directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, include, include-path

This error has always annoyed me and never got to understand how to solve it, so I would like to finally learn how to do things properly.

So I follow this:

1) Create empty Win32 console application (C++)

2) Create main.cpp

3) I have a library "FreeImage.h", which I copy under "./include/FreeImage.h".

4) I click on Add Existing Files and add FreeImage.h to my project.

5) I click on Project - Properties, and in VC++ Directories, I add the absolute path to the previously mentioned "include" folder. I repeat the same operation under the C/C++ - General tab, under "Additional Include directories".

Then I have this in main.cpp:

```
#include <FreeImage.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Then, when I compile, it complains: "Could not find FreeImage.h".
Why on earth can Visual Studio not find it? I set the absolute path to the "include" folder twice...

Thanks!

Comment: Try using quote marks (") instead of angle brackets. The angle brackets tell the compiler to start its search in the compiler's directory tree instead of your project's directory tree.

Comment: Did you set the appropriate configuration target under the Properties window? http://i.imgur.com/ZKoC8zb.png

Comment: @Logicrat If I use quotes, it works with #include "include/FreeImage.h". But I expected that to work, since quotes mean "relative to the current path", if I am not mistaken. On the other hand, I was expecting that using <> if would search in the search directories I specify (plus the compiler directories).

Comment: @Anno That was the solution! I had to click on "All configurations" and add the "include" directory there. Pretty weird since I did it for both Release and Debug... But good to know anyway, thanks a lot!